# With click being handled in `addEventListener`, the change of state on click happens only once. [React Hooks]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add third party Status Widget to a page. I am using the `addEventListener` to handle click, because `onClick` does not work (the third party code is already handling the click and I need to overwrite it). But for some reason the component rerenders only on first click. Then, even though the click event happens (it is logged in console), the state does not update and the component does not rerender.

I tried using `React.useCallback` for managing state, but it did not solve the issue.

```
const StatusWidget = () => {
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
const ref = useRef(null);

const toggleClass = () => {
    console.log('clicked');
    popup.setAttribute('data-open', !selected);
    setSelected(!selected);
};

useEffect(() => {
  new Status.Widget({
    hostname: 'exmple.hostname',
    selector: '#status',
    css: true,
    privacyBypassToken: 'some token',
    includePrivacyBypassTokenInLinks: true,
    debug: false
  });

  popup = document.querySelector('.status-widget__pane');

  [ref.current, popup].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => toggleClass()));
},[]);

return (
  <div id='status' ref={ref} className={cx(selected && 'selected')} />
 );
};

export default StatusWidget;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is stale enclosure of the initial `selected` state, so you will always be toggling from the same old value from the initial render and no subsequent render cycles see an updated state.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to enqueue state updates from the previous state, versus state from the render cycle the state was enclosed in.

```
const toggleClass = () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  popup.setAttribute('data-open', !selected);
  setSelected(selected => !selected); // <-- functional state update.
};
```

Don't forget to clean up your listeners in the `useEffect`'s cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  new Status.Widget({
    hostname: 'exmple.hostname',
    selector: '#status',
    css: true,
    privacyBypassToken: 'some token',
    includePrivacyBypassTokenInLinks: true,
    debug: false
  });

  popup = document.querySelector('.status-widget__pane');

  [ref.current, popup].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', toggleClass));

  return () => {
    [ref.current, popup].forEach(el => el.removeEventListener('click', toggleClass));
  };
},[]);
```